# a question on the compactness of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(\mathbb{R},T)$ be a topological space such that $T=\{(-v,v):v \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}\}$. Show that $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact. Does there exist a minimal covering? That is, does there exist $C \subset T$ such that $\bigcup C = \mathbb{R}$ and, for every $C^{*} \subset C$ such that $C^{*} \neq C$, $\bigcup{C^*} \neq \mathbb{R}$.

I have 5 questions like this and I'm not really sure where to begin , if someone could provide me with an example to get me started that would be really great :)

Comment: What does S mean in this context? For instance, what does S U∈A mean?

Comment: Can you think about a covering of $\mathbb{R}$ Present a single example of such a covering and we can try to help you from there.

Comment: would the correct covering be C={
(−v, v)| v ∈ R
(+)
 }

Comment: and yes T is the topology on R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When given a topology, the first step is to verify if it is actually a topology.
Let's do this for $T$.
First note that $\mathbb{R}=(-\infty,\infty)\in T$ and $\emptyset=(0,0)\in T$.
For closure under finite intersections, suppose $(-v,v),(-w,w)\in T$ and deduce $(-v,v)\cup(-w,w)=(-(v\vee w),v\vee w)\in T$, where $v\vee w$ denotes the maximum of $v$ and $w$.
Finally, if $((-v_i,v_i))_{i\in I}$ is a family of open sets, then $v:=\sup_{i\in I}v_i\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ exists and
$$
\bigcup_{i\in I}(-v_i,v_i) = (-v,v)\in T.
$$
Therefore $(\mathbb{R},T)$ is a topological space. Note that this is different from the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, since the set $(1,2)$ is not open in $(\mathbb{R},T)$.

To show that $(\mathbb{R},T)$ is not compact, consider the open covering $\{(-n,n) : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ of $(\mathbb{R},T)$.

To answer the question about a minimal covering, look at $C:=\{(-\infty,\infty)\}$.

Comment: $\{\Bbb R\}$ is the only minimal open cover.

Comment: so C={ (−v, v)| v ∈ R (+)} would be te correct minimal covering ?

Comment: @jamiemma1995 No. The set of all $(-v,v)$ for $v>1$ is a proper subset of $C$ that covers the space.